# Check if string contains only lowercase letters and symbols

Tags: c#, regex

I have to check if string contains only **lowercase** letters, from **'d'** onwards, **and the symbols '{', '}', '|', '#'.**

I have tried to create Regex but it matches substrings which is not the desired behaviour (the second test **mustn't** match in the example which I add). I don't know how to explain that the order **isn't important** and the strings must **contain** **only** of the **allowed** characters. [Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/DJHw23/2)

> [d-z]+[{}|#]+

This regex matches a**rx#vkdww#qrw#sdvv** and this isn't right. How can I fix it?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: @Thefourthbird, But I've edited it and it's still on hold. Doesn't matter. You are really good at Regex. Thank you! I'll try to understand it now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your pattern `[d-z]+[{}|#]+` matches 1+ times a char `d-z` in a character class followed by one of the chars listed in the character class `[{}|#]+`

You have to use anchors to assert the start `^` and end `$` of the string and use 1 character class containing all the allowed characters instead of 2:

```
^[d-z{}|#]*$
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/FQkISg/1)